# "Could not resolve dependencies" with cabal due to MonadCatchIO-transformers

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am trying to build a package to deploy using [propellor](https://propellor.branchable.com/), and have not even been able to get it to configure due to dependency issues.

Here is the error message that I get:

```
$ cabal new-configure
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: prod-0.0.1 (user goal)
trying: base-4.9.1.0/installed-4.9... (dependency of prod-0.0.1)
trying: transformers-0.5.2.0/installed-0.5... (dependency of propellor-2.17.0)
next goal: MonadCatchIO-transformers (dependency of prod-0.0.1)
rejecting: MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.3.1.3 (conflict:
base==4.9.1.0/installed-4.9..., MonadCatchIO-transformers => base<4.9)
rejecting: MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.3.1.2,
MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.3.1.1, MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.3.1.0
(conflict: base==4.9.1.0/installed-4.9..., MonadCatchIO-transformers =>
base<4.8)
rejecting: MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.3.0.0,
MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.2.2.3, MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.2.2.2,
MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.2.2.1, MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.2.2.0,
MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.2.1.0, MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.2.0.0
(conflict: base==4.9.1.0/installed-4.9..., MonadCatchIO-transformers =>
base<4.7)
rejecting: MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.1.0.1 (conflict:
transformers==0.5.2.0/installed-0.5..., MonadCatchIO-transformers =>
transformers==0.1.*)
rejecting: MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.1.0.0,
MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.0.2.0, MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.0.1.0
(conflict: transformers==0.5.2.0/installed-0.5..., MonadCatchIO-transformers
=> transformers<0.2)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

It seems that the package 'MonadCatchIO-transformers' package requires an older version of 'base', and a much older version of transformers.

I have tried following the advice of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904909/what-to-do-if-libraries-require-a-different-version-of-base) post (editing the configuration of MonadCatchIO-transformers and then installing) to override these requirements, but somehow get the same error message.

I have also tried many other things including this with and without sandboxes, and reinstalling my entire ghc, etc. Is there any way out of this cabal hell?

Comment: That's not really 'cabal hell'; You seem to have a dependency on an old deprecated package that you probably shouldn't be having.

Comment: Considered using stack?

Comment: @Reactormonk Stack is a great tool, but it isn't an automatic solution for every dependency management issue. In this case, the symptoms indicate that, without making additional adjustments, the OP would have run into the exact same problem with Stack (cf. Cubic's comment).

Comment: Is `prod` your local package? How did you create its `.cabal` file? Maybe you were following out-dated instructions, or using an old version of `propellor` to create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should do when facing unsatisfiable dependencies for Hackage packages is [checking the package documentation at Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadCatchIO-transformers) to have a broader picture of the problem. In this case, the documentation reveals that *MonadCatchIO-transformers* was deprecated in favour of the [*exceptions*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.3.1.3) package, that provides a similar interface (which explains why *MonadCatchIO-transforemrs* wasn't updated for *base* 4.9). That being so, you have basically three approaches for getting your package to build:

#### 1. Switch your code to *exceptions*

Since *MonadCatchIO-transformers* appears to be a dependency that you are directly using in your code (as opposed to a transitive dependency), the recommended long-term solution is updating your code to use *exceptions* rather than *MonadCatchIO-transformers*.

#### 2. Use GHC 7.10 for this project

If you can't, or don't want to, switch to *exceptions* right now, an alternative is setting up a parallel GHC 7.10.x installation, so that you can use *base* 4.8. Suggestions of ways to conveniently using *cabal-install* with multiple versions of GHC are presented in [*Using cabal with multiple GHC versions*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7770100/2751851) (through *cabal* settings -- be sure to also read the more recent answers further down the page) and in [this blog post by Edsko de Vries](http://www.edsko.net/2015/03/09/sandboxes-revisited/) (by managing your bash environment). Another possibility is using [Stack](https://www.haskellstack.org/) (rather than *cabal-install*) to build this specific project and switching to a resolver that provides *base* 4.8 and *MonadCatchIO-transformers* (such as the [LTS 6.30](https://www.stackage.org/lts-6.30) Stackage snapshot), as Stack can install and manage alternative GHC versions for projects that require it (cf. the `stack setup` command). Stack doesn't interfere with your usual *cabal-install* environment or with your system-wide GHC installation; that being so, if you switch this project to Stack you can remain using *cabal-install* everywhere else just fine.

#### 3. Adjust the upper bounds of *MonadCatchIO-transformers*

There is also approach of installing a custom version of *MonadCatchIO-transformers* with adjusted upper bounds of *base* and *transformers*. While that may be the quickest way to get it up and running, in this case it is also the least sustainable one, considering that *MonadCatchIO-transformers* [has been deprecated for several years already](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2013-November/111309.html). As for why that didn't work for you...

> I have tried following the advice of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904909/what-to-do-if-libraries-require-a-different-version-of-base) post (editing the configuration of MonadCatchIO-transformers and then installing) to override these requirements, but somehow get the same error message.

... the fact you got *literally* the same error message suggests that *cabal-install* didn't pick your custom *MonadCatchIO-transformers* version. Have you changed the version of *MonadCatchIO-transformers*, both in the .cabal file you changed (as suggested in the Q&A you linked to) and in the .cabal file of your project?